# What value should I pass in NSPopover's showRelativeToRect:ofView:preferredEdge: method's ofView: parameter?

Tags: objective-c, macos, nspopover

I am looking online for an answer since yesterday, but *NSPopover* doesn't seem to get a lot of attention.

The thing is I haven't understood the *ofView:* parameter exactly. When I look at some code examples I see that they were always able to get away by passing *self.view* or a *view object* they created inside of the method they created the *NSPopover* object. Now instead of looking at the examples I want to understand it in a way that I can apply it to any example by myself.

Apple documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nspopover/1532113-showrelativetorect?language=objc) explains ofView:(NSView *)positioningView as  *"the view relative to which the popover should be positioned."* 
But I would like a more fundamental explanation if anyone has a grasp on it.

There might be some edits needed for the question. However, this is by no means a duplicate.

Comment: I can't really explain it any better than the documentation - it is just the view that the popover is, umm, popping from.  The examples you are seeing may be actions or delegate methods, where the containing view can be retrieved from the object.

Comment: It's (the area of) the view that the arrow of the popover points to.